# Woo commerce product quantity wise SKU

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In woocommerce i have multiple readymade garment VARIABLE product all have multiple variations with size and colour, I want now variations stock wise SKU field
Suppose I have variations of t-shirt yellow XL size 5 quantity I want 5 SKU fields.
So in short i want product quantity wise SKU in VARIABLE & simple product both.
Thanks

Comment: What? your question is difficult to understand, WooCommerce already has sku/stock for each variation you create.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, I want product stock quantity wise SKU. Suppose I have 5 quantity of product i want to enter 5 different SKU

Comment: So if a simple product has 20 in stock you want that single product to have 20 skus? and if a variable product has 5 variations and each variation has 10 in stock you will have 10 * 5 skus? That is very strange, what's the reason behind this?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Yes correct, actually here one local garment shop with multiple outlets so all outlets have many same variations products so they want now enter in e-commerce business so they have currently desktop applications that provide same with quantity variations wise barcode, so if any product sale from website they can track from which outlets that product sales

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Any solution ?